# Issues with uploading images to a carousel

Tags: ajax, django, dynamic, carousel, image-upload

OK, so here's the deal:

This is currently what I'm working on:
[image]

See the two arrows at the top? That's where a carousel of pictures should be. However, there are no pictures in this carousel. That is, until I click the 'Upload' Button.

[image: I used old screenshots to test the uploads.]

So, my goal is to make the pictures appear on the first page before I even click the 'upload' button.

How can I fix this problem? I'm kind of a noob at [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29), and writing this code is like pulling teeth.

My code:

#### Index.html

```
{% extends 'webportal/defaults.html' %}
{% block body %}
    {% include 'webportal/carousel.html' %}

    <br/>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p> So far we have been able to establish what the user tables will be have created or are in process of
                    creating
                    the ability to create, update, destroy users.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p> For now this ability is limited to the main user table, however the models will be easily extended
                    to other
                    tables as they are needed</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p> Also not a lot of thought has gone into styling yet, we know that the page is suppose to resemble
                    the parent
                    organizations page. Right now we have been more focused on getting each individual component
                    working. Later we
                    will merge them into a whole. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    {% include 'webportal/info_row.html' with one=one two=two three=three %}
{% endblock %}
```

Carousel.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load filename %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    {% for document in documents %}
                        <div class="item {% if forloop.first %} active {% endif %}">
                           <div class="row">
                             <div class="col">
                               <li><a href = "{{document.docfile.url}}">{{document.docfile.name}}</a></li>
                               <img src = "{{STATIC_URL}}img/{{document|filename}}" >
                               <p align="center"><form style="text-align:center" action="{% url 'webportal:delete' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                   {% csrf_token %}
                                   <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
                                   <p>{{ form.Document.label_tag }} {{ form.Document.help_text }}</p>
                                   <p>
                                       {{ form.Document.errors }}
                                       {{ form.Document.docfile }}
                                   </p>
                                   <p><input type="submit" value="Delete" /></p>
                               </form></p>
                             </div>
                           </div>
                         </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.carousel -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <form action="{% url 'webportal:carousel' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
        <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} {{ form.docfile.help_text }}</p>
        <p>
            {{ form.docfile.errors }}
            {{ form.docfile }}
        </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

#### Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from webportal.views.authentication import LoginForm
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.conf import settings
from webportal.forms.forms import DocumentForm
from webportal.models import Document, DeleteForm
is_server = True
def delete(request, my_id):
    Deleted=get_object_or_404(Document, docfile=my_id)
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=DeleteForm(request.POST, instance=Deleted)
        if form.is_valid():
            Deleted.delete()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/alzheimers/')
    else:
        form=DeleteForm(instance=Deleted)
    return render_to_response(
        'webportal/index.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form,},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )

# Redirect to the document list after POST
def carousel(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/alzheimers/')
   else:
       form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form
# Load documents for the list page
   documents = Document.objects.all()
#documents=DocumentForm().
# Render list page with the documents and the form
   return render_to_response(
    'webportal/index.html',
    {'documents': documents, 'form': form,},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
)
```

#### Models.py:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.ImageField(upload_to='webportal/static/img/')
class DeleteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Document
        fields=[]
```

#### Forms.py:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.ImageField(label='Select a file', help_text='max. 42 megabytes')
```

URls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url 

from webportal.views import views, register, authentication, welcome, search, profile, event, csv_export, role_creation, \ 
    edit_event, reports, accounts 



urlpatterns = patterns('', 
                       url(r'^reports', reports.report_page), 
                       url(r'^search/criteria', search.get_criteria), 
                       url(r'^search', search.search_page), 
                       url(r'^register', register.SignUpView.as_view(), name="register"), 
                       url(r'^login', authentication.login_view, name="login"), 
                       url(r'^carousel', views.carousel, name="carousel"), 
                       url(r'^delete', views.delete, name="delete"),  
                       url(r'^profile', profile.ProfileView.as_view(), name="profile"), 
                       url(r'^welcome', welcome.WelcomeView.as_view(), name="welcome"), 

                       url(r'^event/creation', event.Creation.as_view(), name="event_creation"), 
                       # url(r'^role_creation', role_creation.Creation.as_view(), name="role_creation"), 
                       url(r'^csv_export', csv_export.CSVExport.as_view(), name="csv_export"), 
                       url(r'^csv_import', reports.upload_file, name="csv_import"), 
                       url(r'^logout$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/alzheimers/'}), 
                       url(r'^edit_event', edit_event.EditView.as_view(), name='edit_event'), 
                       url(r'^parse_ajax', profile.parse_ajax), 
                       url(r'^event/role_ajax', role_creation.ajax), 
                       url(r'^event/all', event.view_all), 
                       url(r'^event/information', event.ajax), 
                       url(r'^accounts/personal', accounts.personal), 
                       url(r'^accounts/create', accounts.create), 
                       url(r'^accounts/edit', accounts.edit), 
                       url(r'^accounts/remove', accounts.remove), 
                       url(r'^$', views.bootstrap), 
)
```

#### If there is a way to do this, does it involve ajax? I asked this again because of a lack of an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the `documents` context variable to the template in the view which handles the `/alzheimers/` page.

**UPDATE**: The view you should change is the `views.boostrap()`.  So rendering of the template will be something like this:

```
def bootstrap(request):
   ...
   return render_to_response('webportal/bootstrap.html',
                             {'documents': Document.objects.all()},
                             context_instance=RequestContext(request)
   )
```

Comment: What if there is no such view?  Is ajax involved? @catavaran

Comment: Hm, the **is** a view which runs when user access the `/alzheimers/` page.  What is in your `urls.py` for this url?

Comment: can you clarify?  @catavaran I don't have one for my index.html.

Comment: urls have been added. @catavaran

Comment: `boostrap()` is the view that handles the `/alzheimers/` url.  See the update in my answer.